# why not postgresql transaction block raise an error?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgesql db, I created a table like below zzz_sil6. column b is date datatype.

```
create table zzz_sil6
(
b date
)
```

if i execute sql as below with only insert statement, it raise an error due to data type problem. This is the case we expected.

```
insert into zzz_sil6
select 1;
```

However, when i executed the insert statement in begin end transaction block, it didnt raise an error due to data type problem.

```
begin
insert into zzz_sil6
select 1;
commit;
end;
```

Am i missing about transaction block? I m new to postgresql.

Comment: How are you executing this?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your application, not the database: ERROR:  column "b" is of type date but expression is of type integer

Comment: Yes, this is not reproducible. This bizarre syntax wouldn't work with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you. It was all about client (dbeaver).